# Jenkins configSubmit postBack aborting

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, postback

Jenkins does not save any configuration when I make changes and click on "Save". I loaded the page on Firefox with Firebug, and I see that my postBacks are being aborted. I tried it on Chrome, and I get a "No data received". What am I doing wrong?

I installed Jenkins on an EC2 instance, and configured it to listen on port 8888. I opened the port on the EC2 console, as well as in iptables.

I then installed Apache2 and used it to provide a Proxy on port 9001, and opened that port as well, both in the EC2 inbound rules and in iptables. (When the setup starts to work, I'll close one of these ports.)

Jenkins is accessible through both ports.

Edit: I've also tried disabling iptables, the problem persists.

Edit: I've realized that the problem is with accessing Jenkins from outside. I logged in via SSH and accessed the site using elinks, and everything worked fine. However, elinks, being a text-browser, is a pain to use, and not all of the site is really usable this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for several hours, I decided to try doing this on a different internet provider. Voila, things started working. I assume this is a problem with my Internet Service Provider, as this works perfectly on my work network.